# Send Json data from one application to another application running on different port using Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I have both main back-end and front-end web-app deployed in tomcat and another application an sms gateway also deployed in tomcat but without a front-end UI. 
The main app is accessible from https://localhost:443/client-app and the sms gateway is running on http://localhost:9191/message-gateway-0.0.1 but the endpoint for sending sms is http://localhost:9191/message-gateway-0.0.1/sms.
From the AngularJs web-app running on https://localhost:443/client-app, i would like to be able to design a simple UI for send sms.

Submit function is as follows:-

```
scope.submit = function () {
    var messagejson = {};
    messagejson.internalId = '55';
    messagejson.mobileNumber = +9128877477433;
    messagejson.message = 'DEAR IPPEZ, Your ATM Card is read for collection at our Head Office.;
    messagejson.providerId = '2';
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:9191/message-gateway-0.0.1/sms',
        data: messagejson,
        headers: {
            "Tenant-App-Key": 'e4600907-f884-4abe-b50b-1c26cc349871'
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    if (response.data)
        alert(response.status + ": SMS message sent Successfully!);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert(response.status + ": Service not Exists);
    });
};
```

On submitting no message is sent and when i inspect the web-console, i see error as below [WebConsole Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah84p.png)
Yet from POSTMAN, its successful.

Any assistance and workaround is highly appreciated. Thanks

[Postman Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z3J3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably face CORS issues. Browsers disallow sending requests between different domains (*localhost:443* and *localhost:9191*). Postman is not a browser, so it works.

You have 2 options:

1. [Enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/) in your SMS app. You have to add special response headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) and you are ready to go.
2. Create backend-backend communication. In this case, your flow should be like: client-app UI -> client-app backend -> message-gateway backend. It sounds better to me as you can have some extra validations in your client-app backend.